# Can't add components in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I have Android Studio on Ubuntu 17.10, and I am trying to add components to the screen design, like so:

[image]

When I try to drag a component onto the screen, it only shows up as a small dot, that I can't move or change the dimensions of, like in the picture below.

[image]

I can't make it visible, drag it about, and clicking the magic wand button to infer constraints. How can I fix this and start editing components properly?

Comment: your using the constraint layout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout so you you'll probably need to read up on how that works

Comment: Apparently this was related to the `Base.Theme` bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to add anything until I changed the line in `style.xml` from  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`, adding `Base` before `Theme` fixed my problem.